# Lost current user (shutdown/logoff) widget after upgrading to Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, gnome-panel

I've upgraded to 10.04 from 9.10. Everything went fine until I've rebooted. After reboot, I've received some message about status panel and being sleepy, dismissed it. However, I haven't seen the user widget on Gnome Panel since that.

This image shows which widget I'm talking about. If some one has any ideas about how it's called properly, please share.

[image]

Anyway, the question is, how do I turn this panel (and ability to shut my system down without resorting to console) back?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right click on gnome panel (that black thing at the top), select 'Add to panel' in menu and then in dialog find either 'indicator applet session' or 'shut down' applet and just double click on it. It'll appear on your panel immediately.

Now close the dialog, right click on your new widget, select 'Move' and move it to the position you want it to be.

Comment: Wow )
I'm using Ubuntu for 2 years now but have never known about this feature. Thanks!